# Google map app created by android studio loads no map

Tags: android, google-maps

Need help , tired of following the tutorials but still no results. I am using android studio and trying to make map app. Tried using the map template in studio as it is just by entering my key bt no matter what i do , i get the same results, blank screen with google log. Google maps console shows zero request from my key to accces maps.

Comment: You can see this [sample Android Google Maps demo](https://github.com/jbj88817/GoogleMapExample-android) from GitHub.

Comment: Thanx ztan , the sample you shown is running without any issue but when I try same coding in my project with my api key , I run into same issue ie, no map loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you devs for support but I solved my problem myself by digging whole day , after implementing maps layout activity and manifest and other required files , the app should be build with the keystore provided in android sdk itself instead of our own keystore. keystore path - C/user/{username}/.android/debug.keystore with alias as "androiddebugkey" and password as "android".

Answer (score 0):

you must add api key, for  this need   register your application in the Google Developers Console
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Comment: Do I need to configure anything in android studio or import library after using the default map templet ?, I have google maps api and repository showing installed in sdk manager.

Comment: If you did everything in tutorial, try create new debug key ─ android studia and intellij idea do not do it, from for it problem with a sha1  key after a year

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you need to create a project on [Google Devlopers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/).
See [this](http://glennsayers.com/android-mapping/) tutorial.